# looping through List android

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

I have the following method:

```
 public List<String> getAllValue(){
       List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
       if(pref.getString(KEY_NUMBER1 , "").length()>2)
           list.add(pref.getString(KEY_NUMBER1 , ""));
       if(pref.getString(KEY_NUMBER2 , "").length()>2)
           list.add(pref.getString(KEY_NUMBER2 , ""));
       if(pref.getString(KEY_NUMBER3 , "").length()>2)
           list.add(pref.getString(KEY_NUMBER3 , ""));
       if(pref.getString(KEY_NUMBER4 , "").length()>2)
           list.add(pref.getString(KEY_NUMBER4 , ""));
       if(pref.getString(KEY_NUMBER5 , "").length()>2)
           list.add(pref.getString(KEY_NUMBER5 , ""));

       return list;
   }
```

What I need to do now is to assign these numbers(like `KEY_NUMBER1`) to the following `editTexts`:

```
EditText phoneNumber1, phoneNumber2, phoneNumber3, phoneNumber4, phoneNumber5;
```

Being new to working with Lists, I am having a hard time trying to figure out a way to loop through and assign values to these editTexts, like

```
phoneNumber1.setText(KEY_NUMBER1);
phoneNumber2.setText(KEY_NUMBER2);
phoneNumber3.setText(KEY_NUMBER3);
```

Comment: `list.get(0);` `list.get(1);` etc will give you values at index 0 and 1. You can loop over the list till [size](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/List.html#size%28%29)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Assuming `list` is your `List<String>` retuned from the function. You may loop over it like:

```
for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(list.get(i));
}
```

For assigning the EditText, you can just use the index, if you the number of items and it is fixed( which seem to be 5 here):

```
phoneNumber1.setText(list.get(0));
phoneNumber2.setText(list.get(1));
//so on ...
```

Comment: do I do the assignment of the phoneNumbers inside the list ?? or do I do it outside of it ... dont mind me asking.

Comment: Sorry i think i got it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

**KOTLIN:**

```
val numbers = listOf("one", "two", "three", "four")
for (item in numbers) {
    println(item)
}
```

or

```
val numbers = listOf("one", "two", "three", "four")
val numbersIterator = numbers.iterator()
while (numbersIterator.hasNext()) {
    println(numbersIterator.next())
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
for (E element : list) {
    . . .
}
```